# My JavaFx application freezes randomly with jdk 8 and Mac OSX

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8

My JavaFx application freezes randomly with jdk 8 and Mac OSX.
logs are smooth and i find nothing in logs.

I am attaching Thread dump may be this will help.
please suggest what is wrong with my application.
This application runs successfully with jdk1.7.0_76. Only JDK change starts this issue

```
2019-12-02 17:27:11
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.221-b11 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" #30 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4a80c000 nid=0xd623 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Library Resource" #29 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b2b8000 nid=0xcb33 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000700480af2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findNative(ClassLoader.java:1960)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007809a1c50> (a java.util.Vector)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketClose0(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.socketPreClose(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:693)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.close(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:530)
    - locked <0x00000007b1957da8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.close(SocksSocketImpl.java:1075)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:369)
    - locked <0x00000007b1957d20> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.library.connections.MySSLSocketFactory.createSocket(MySSLSocketFactory.java:145)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.library.connections.IsmHTTPSAbstractClientConnection.createConnection(IsmHTTPSAbstractClientConnection.java:97)
    - locked <0x00000007b1918ae0> (a org.ism.mvp.model.library.services.upload.HttpsClientConnectionFRUpload)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.library.connections.AbstractConnectionFactory.getConnectionInstanceForUpload(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:136)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.library.services.upload.connection.CreateLibConnInBGFrUpload.createConnectionInBG(CreateLibConnInBGFrUpload.java:72)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.library.services.upload.connection.CreateLibConnInBGFrUpload.run(CreateLibConnInBGFrUpload.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Load License Thread" #28 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4ae58800 nid=0x6e0f runnable [0x0000700440aed000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    - locked <0x00000007809a1e18> (a java.util.Vector)
    - locked <0x00000007809a1c50> (a java.util.Vector)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    - locked <0x00000007809ed658> (a java.lang.Runtime)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    - locked <0x00000007809a1e18> (a java.util.Vector)
    - locked <0x00000007809a1c50> (a java.util.Vector)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    - locked <0x00000007809ed658> (a java.lang.Runtime)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1670)
    at java.awt.Font.<clinit>(Font.java:246)
    at com.aspose.slides.FontsLoader.do(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.FontsLoader.loadExternalFonts(Unknown Source)
    at org.mvp.powerpoint.PresentationCreation.loadLicense(PresentationCreation.java:58)
    at org.ism.mvp.view.controller.ISMPPTController.loadLicenseFile(ISMPPTController.java:254)
    at org.ism.mvp.view.controller.ISMPPTController$1.run(ISMPPTController.java:129)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Open-Last/Previous Thread" #27 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b636800 nid=0x6f13 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000700400aec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findNative(ClassLoader.java:1960)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007809a1c50> (a java.util.Vector)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketClose0(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.socketPreClose(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:693)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.close(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:530)
    - locked <0x00000007810a60b8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.close(SocksSocketImpl.java:1075)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:369)
    - locked <0x00000007810a6030> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.library.connections.IsmHTTPAbstractClientConnection.createConnection(IsmHTTPAbstractClientConnection.java:84)
    - locked <0x00000007b1319488> (a org.ism.mvp.model.library.services.search.HttpClientConnection)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.library.connections.AbstractConnectionFactory.getConnectionInstanceForSearch(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:90)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.library.services.search.connection.ConnectLibraryInBackground.run(ConnectLibraryInBackground.java:48)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"snapshot creation" #26 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4ae77000 nid=0xe703 in Object.wait() [0x00007003c0aea000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000078040d6b0> (a org.ism.mvp.model.editor.IsmSnpNThumbBGProcessMgr)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.editor.IsmSnpNThumbBGProcessMgr.run(IsmSnpNThumbBGProcessMgr.java:53)
    - locked <0x000000078040d6b0> (a org.ism.mvp.model.editor.IsmSnpNThumbBGProcessMgr)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Background Process" #25 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b5ee800 nid=0xe60b in Object.wait() [0x0000700380ae7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000078040d4b8> (a org.ism.mvp.model.editor.IsmEditListBGProcessMgr)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.editor.IsmEditListBGProcessMgr.waitForEvent(IsmEditListBGProcessMgr.java:61)
    - locked <0x000000078040d4b8> (a org.ism.mvp.model.editor.IsmEditListBGProcessMgr)
    at org.ism.mvp.model.editor.IsmEditListBGProcessMgr.run(IsmEditListBGProcessMgr.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"PulseTimer-CVDisplayLink thread" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b378800 nid=0xe20f runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Timer-1" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4ab89000 nid=0xdf03 in Object.wait() [0x0000700340a61000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000780904d98> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x0000000780904d98> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"process reaper" #21 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4ad7c000 nid=0x8e2b waiting on condition [0x00007001c0974000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007801031c0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Timer-0" #20 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4ad4b000 nid=0xdd1f waiting for monitor entry [0x0000700300a5d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findNative(ClassLoader.java:1960)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007809a1c50> (a java.util.Vector)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketClose0(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.socketPreClose(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:693)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.close(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:530)
    - locked <0x00000007ac8a1288> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.close(SocksSocketImpl.java:1075)
    at java.net.Socket.close(Socket.java:1495)
    - locked <0x00000007ac8a11e0> (a java.lang.Object)
    - locked <0x00000007ac8a1130> (a java.net.Socket)
    at org.ism.mvp.view.model.IsmSnapshotGeneratorBGProcess.hostAvailabilityCheck(IsmSnapshotGeneratorBGProcess.java:144)
    at org.ism.mvp.view.model.IsmSnapshotGeneratorBGProcess.ismSnapshotGeneratorProcRunning(IsmSnapshotGeneratorBGProcess.java:67)
    - locked <0x00000007808edfc8> (a org.ism.mvp.view.model.IsmSnapshotGeneratorBGProcess)
    at org.ism.mvp.view.model.IsmSnapshotGeneratorBGProcess.run(IsmSnapshotGeneratorBGProcess.java:53)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Error Handling Thread" #18 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4acf5800 nid=0x8f0b in Object.wait() [0x00007002c0a5b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000078032b0f0> (a org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread)
    at org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread.waitForEvent(Logger.java:339)
    - locked <0x000000078032b0f0> (a org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread)
    at org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread.logWriter(Logger.java:361)
    at org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread.run(Logger.java:334)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Error Handling Thread" #17 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4ace2800 nid=0xda1b in Object.wait() [0x0000700280a58000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000780905830> (a org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread)
    at org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread.waitForEvent(Logger.java:339)
    - locked <0x0000000780905830> (a org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread)
    at org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread.logWriter(Logger.java:361)
    at org.ism.mvp.Logger$ErrorQueueThread.run(Logger.java:334)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Prism Font Disposer" #15 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b2ff800 nid=0xd803 in Object.wait() [0x0000700240a55000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000780178e80> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    - locked <0x0000000780178e80> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"JavaFX-Launcher" #13 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4ab8c800 nid=0xb007 waiting on condition [0x0000700200a52000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007808f3d20> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:873)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/2027961269.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"JavaFX Application Thread" #11 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b1cb800 nid=0x160b runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-1" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4aae1800 nid=0x5a03 in Object.wait() [0x00007001c0843000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000780901868> (a java.lang.StringBuilder)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:126)
    - locked <0x0000000780901868> (a java.lang.StringBuilder)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"QuantumRenderer-0" #8 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b110000 nid=0x4703 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007001807ba000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:801)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007809ed658> (a java.lang.Runtime)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    - locked <0x00000007808d6fd8> (a java.lang.Class for com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.shape.NativePiscesRasterizer.lambda$static$0(NativePiscesRasterizer.java:76)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.shape.NativePiscesRasterizer$$Lambda$297/2120169674.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.shape.NativePiscesRasterizer.<clinit>(NativePiscesRasterizer.java:70)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.shape.ShapeUtil.<clinit>(ShapeUtil.java:39)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.renderShape(BaseShaderGraphics.java:463)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseGraphics.draw(BaseGraphics.java:401)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.CachingShapeRepState.drawNoCache(CachingShapeRep.java:406)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.CachingShapeRepState.render(CachingShapeRep.java:484)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.CachingShapeRep.draw(CachingShapeRep.java:113)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGShape.renderContent2D(NGShape.java:293)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGShape.renderContent(NGShape.java:261)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:577)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:577)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderNodeBlendMode(NGNode.java:2150)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2038)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:577)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:477)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:330)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x0000000780328280> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
    - <0x0000000780686930> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

"Service Thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b046000 nid=0x4303 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b004800 nid=0x4103 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b032000 nid=0x3f03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4a86a000 nid=0x3c0b runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4a85a000 nid=0x3903 in Object.wait() [0x00007000c04ab000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000780108e88> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    - locked <0x0000000780108e88> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4a857000 nid=0x3703 in Object.wait() [0x00007000804a8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000780925a80> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x0000000780925a80> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4a81b000 nid=0x2b03 waiting on condition [0x000070004019b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007808f4740> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:200)
    at org.ism.mvp.MedicalVideoProducer.main(MedicalVideoProducer.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b02b800 nid=0x3503 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b008800 nid=0x3103 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b009000 nid=0x3303 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8c4b048800 nid=0x4503 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 775
```

comming with jdk_1.8.0_221
Mac OSX

Comment: You seem to have a lot of threads waiting for to lock <0x00000007809a1c50> which is owned by "Load License Thread" trying to load a font. If that's something you can change, maybe try using a different font.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Why this is coming random and only on Mac?

Comment: The fonts are probably handled differently between the JVM version and the OS, each layer might add their own bugs/undocumented behaviour

Comment: I saw my code.I am using library of Aspose for generating powerpoint. for this I am Loading Fonts but I do this in background thread. here is the code

FontsLoader.loadExternalFonts(new String[]{"/Library/Fonts", "/Library/Fonts/Microsoft"});

And I saw in Mac It having big no of font typs

Comment: Well I'm not sure what  FontsLoader does but I would not be surprised if "/Library/Fonts/Microsoft" does not exist on a Mac

Comment: yes it's not present there